# Merge two lines into one and add character

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'v got a output like:

```
TEXT
SOMETEXTELSE
```

I need to merge the strings and add symbol "R" betwen them like:

```
TEXT R SOMETEXTELSE
```

How i can do it?

Thanks

Update. Sorry. Here is the comand

```
egrep -B1 ELLDB@сranium.*FAILED /var/log/alert.log | tail -2
```

Here is the output:

```
ERR-0045 Database is down for given SID. Can't perform backup.
2014-12-19 16:15:01 ELLDB@сranium Backuper:bkp status: FAILED 98456876
```

I need output like:

```
ERR-0045 Database is down for given SID. Can't perform backup. R 2014-12-19 16:15:01 ELLDB@сranium Backuper:bkp status: FAILED 98456876
```

Comment: How big is the file? How do you determine which lines get merged? Is it just these two lines? Need more info.

Comment: Sorry for this. Just updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '$! s/.*/\0 R/' | paste -s -d " "
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say your output is generated by `seq 1 10`, then maybe...

```
seq 1 10 | perl -pe 's/\n/ R /' | perl -pe 's/$/\n/'
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf "%s R ", $0} NR == 2'
```

**Explanation:**

awk reads its input line by line and compares every line to every `pattern` in a series of `pattern {action}` pairs.

`NR == 1 {printf "%s R ", $0}`:

***If*** the current line is the fist line (`NR == 1`), ***then*** execute `printf "%s R ", $0`, which means print the content of the line (`$0`) followed by a space, followed by "R", followed by a space (no newline at the end).

`NR == 2`:

***If*** the current line is the second line (`NR == 2`), ***then*** execute the default action (since no action in `{...}` is specified), which is to print the content of the line followed by a newline (it would be equivalent to write `NR == 2 {print}` or `NR == 2 {print $0}`).

Comment: Consider adding a brief explanation what this snippet does i.e. how it works.

Answer (score 0):

A single `sed` command can be used with the `N` join line substitution.

```
sed -e 'N;s/\n/ R /'
```

For example:

```
$ printf "TEXT\nSOMETEXTELSE\n" | sed -e 'N;s/\n/ R /'
TEXT R SOMETEXTELSE
```